# Check item length, after write clearfix

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Good day to all, I wanna create small jQuery elements, which check item length after write clearfix... For example what I want:

```
var item_lenght = $('.category').length;
console.log(item_lenght);
```

Item length = 12, When item_lenght == 3 after class `.category` write `<div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>`, if item_lenght == 2 write `<div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>` as jQuery append but after class `category`..

For example:

```
 var item_lenght = $('.category').length;
 if (item_lenght == 3) {
     $(".category").after("<div class='clearfix visible-md'></div>")
 } else if (item_lenght == 2) {
     $(".category").after("<div class='clearfix visible-md'></div>")
 }
```

**UPD!**

The initial view:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 category music-item"><a class="category_full_link" href="#">
  <div class="category_img"><img src="images/category/3.png"><span>Soundtrack</span></div></a>
    <h4><a class="two-lines" href="#">Suicide Squad: The Album</a></h4>
    <p class="two-lines">Soundtracks</p>
</div>
```

I want after every 6th `col-lg-2` add the class `clearfix visible-lg`

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 category music-item"><a class="category_full_link" href="#">
  <div class="category_img"><img src="images/category/3.png"><span>Soundtrack</span></div></a>
    <h4><a class="two-lines" href="#">Suicide Squad: The Album</a></h4>
    <p class="two-lines">Soundtracks</p>
</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>
```

**UPD!
After answering maher made this code, using Modernizr.js (maybe can someone come in handy)**

```
$(".col-lg-2.category").each(function(index) {
    if (Modernizr.mq("(min-width:1200px)")) {
      if (index % 6 === 0 && index != 0) {
        $(this).before('<div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>');
      }
    } else if (Modernizr.mq("(min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px)")) {
      if (index % 4 === 0 && index != 0) {
        $(this).before('<div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>');
      }
    } else if (Modernizr.mq("(min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px)")) {
      if (index % 3 === 0 && index != 0) {
        $(this).before('<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>');
      }
    } else if (Modernizr.mq("screen and (max-width:767px)")) {
      if (index % 2 === 0 && index != 0) {
        $(this).before('<div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>');
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your intention correctly, but are you maybe looking for jQuery's `.after()`?

Comment: @Connum oups, yes it's exactly... but How i check this length?

Comment: not clear what you're asking for, could you please give a clear example or elaborate some more.

Comment: As @MaherFattouh stated, please try to explain a bit better what you want to achieve. You are already checking the length, so I don't really get the question. From there, it should only be a switch/case or if/else statement.

Comment: jQuery's .length returns the number of elements in the jQuery object. do you mean `height`?

Comment: @MaherFattouh, please see UPD..

Comment: do you want to add a div after the 3rd `'.catagory'` element?

Comment: or add it after the last `'.catagory'` if the number of elements is equals to 2 or 3?

Comment: @MaherFattouh yes, yes, yes)) So, check out the 4 columns grid

Comment: so what went wrong?

Comment: @FanyoSILIADIN I don't know why it is not working :(

Comment: what do you mean by "it is not working"? you are appending an empty div so if you don't see it doesn't mean it is not working

Comment: why don't you post your html code and the expected result after you call your code. this will clear everything

Comment: @FanyoSILIADIN Emm.. I don't know how else to explain... If you want check lenght your class and after each col-sm-4 you want add div with class for every fourth value, how would you do?

Comment: Please post a before and after HTML code

Comment: @MaherFattouh Okey, one minute

Comment: @MaherFattouh Please, see Update.. in my question

Comment: OK, I updated my answer and added a working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a working example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/Maher-Fa/pen/EZpMyO)

### The Code

```
$(".col-lg-2").each(function(index) {
      if (index % 6 === 0 && index != 0) {
        $(this).before('<div class="clearfix visible-lg">I am an added div</div>');
      };
});
```

we use `.each` to loop through the elements and use `if (index % 6 === 0)` to check for every 6th element and when you find it you use `$(this).before()` to add our content

Comment: Maher, thank you for reply... Your code it's beatiful... But have a little bit problem.. When 2 col-lg together in a row it's working, but when have col-lg (after) -> clearfix visible-xs (or someone class) (after this have again) -> col-lg-2 it's not working.. that is, he does not read.. It's screen https://ibb.co/bD3P5a